# Having numbering in subsubsection header

Tags: header-footer, numbering

I am using [the following template to write my document](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-tu-delft-dissertation/krbgqrskfhdp), however, I have noticed that I do not have numbering in the \subsubsection command. Furthermore, I would like to have something like \subsubsubsection to the document. How can I do these two things?

I tried to use the following commands:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

But it did not properly work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TU-Delft dissertation class does not use `secnumdepth` to control the numbering of sections. I'm not sure how strict TU Delft is on formatting requirements for dissertations (back in my day, I remember stories of department secretaries measuring margins, spacing, etc. with a ruler and rejecting non-conforming dissertations).

The standard section division below `\subsubsection` is `\paragraph`. The TU-Delft dissertation class does not define formatting for that section level, however, so the formatting may not be conformant with university requirements.

Comment: It is a bit weird since now I can see the numbering in the \paragraph but not in the \subsubsection. I do not think that I will have these types of issues. However, it will be weird if I have the numbering for the paragraphs and not the \subsubsection.

Comment: The way the `\subsubsection` command is defined, it doesn't produce numbering regardless of the setting of `secnumdepth` The dissertation class uses the definition of `\paragraph` from the `book` class which does use `secnumdepth` which is why you see the numbering there.

Comment: Bit weird, ok I think I will skip that, it does not make that much of sense.